# Is there any free to use XSD (DTD) for Rx documents (drug prescription)

Tags: xsd, dtd

I'd like to explore and possibly use (reuse) open XML formats/schemes (DTD/XSD) for **drug (medication) prescription documents** (Rx) issued by medical doctors and later processed by licenced pharmacists and health insurance companies.

Is there any such freely XSD available and what I have to take care when considering and incorporating into health-care information system?

What international standards (ISO, ISO/IEC, EN) should be used to achieve the maximum level of **interoperability**?

Comment: I'm curious: are there any closed ones?

Comment: please provide more information about what you want to achieve

Comment: Is this related to NCPDP and XML serialization of the 'telecommunications' standard?

Comment: I don't think it were hard to develop one - if the U.S. Government hadn't done it already.